# Qt5 - QTableView with QtSql

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, qtableview

This is a bit of a follow on question from this one - [Python referencing database connection on another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141694/python-referencing-database-connection-on-another-script)
After managing to get my connection and pull data from the database, I read that using QTableView, as opposed to QTableWidget would be better for what I am trying to achieve. However, I've been struggling to get the table to populate using QTableView, and nearly every example I can find is in C++, rather than Python, and there are so many different terminologies used, it's like a minefield of undecipherable information to me. I've been trying to follow various different tutorials and examples, and I'm now getting an error message saying that QSqlQueryModel isn't defined, which I thought was pre-installed as part of Qt?

Currently, my code is as follows :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
import sys
from ViewClientsTableView import Ui_ViewClients
from OpenConn import open_conn, close_conn

class ViewClientsWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_ViewClients):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ViewClientsWindow, self).__init__()
        self._new_window = None
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.data_load()

    def data_load(self):
        server, db = open_conn()
        model =  QSqlQueryModel()
        model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM Clients")
        model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, tr("ID"))
        model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, tr("Name"))
        view =  QTableView()
        view.setModel(model)
        view.show()
        close_conn(server, db)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = ViewClientsWindow()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Am I approaching things completely wrong? The purpose of this project was to try and make life a little easier, and to free up some valuable time, but currently it's doing the opposite.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated....
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try with `model =  QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()` and `model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")` , `model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Name")` ...i'm facing some trouble with the QtSql module, can't import, so can't test too...

Comment: Change `QSqlQueryModel()` to `QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()`, I also recommend using QSqlTableModel instead of QSqlQueryModel, you just use `setTable("tablename")` to indicate the table.

Comment: If the server functions `server, db = open_conn()` will not work in this case, you must use the PyQt functions to open the connection.

Comment: If you are not doing so already, I would *hugely* recommend you develop in **PyCharm**.  That IDE would immediately help you resolve where your references are wrong (e.g. `QSqlQueryModel()` needs to be `QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()`), apart from all its other goodies.

Comment: I've managed to get past some of the errors, using `model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()` and `model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ID")`, but then I was getting an error = 'QTableView() not defined' - solved that with `view =  QtWidgets.QTableView()`. Now the code runs, but I get 'QSqlQuery::exec: database not open'. I don't quite understand why that wouldn't work, when it was working on the tablewidget view